# Global feed for Slack team including all channels and private messages?

Tags: feeds, slack

Is there a feed in Slack that lists everything that happened in the Slack team in chronological order? (including messages in the channel and private messages)

Here is why I need it: I get a notification in my mobile phone about a team member wrote in a channel. Viewing it on the phone dismisses this notification. When I get back to my desktop, I want to act on that message, but I cannot find that message anymore. I look around in channels, look at the last messages in each channel, try to compare their times, and try to see which one is the latest. This obviously is a difficult situation, especially when I don't remember the contents of the message that I viewed/dismissed on my mobile phone.

If there was a feed in Slack that lists everything that happened in chronological order, I could just look at that and see what happened after what, even when they are in different channels or if they are private messages.

If there is currently a 3rd party integration that does this, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also use `/s after:yesterday` which lists all posts today, in reverse chrono order.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, it seems this is not possible. A Slack representative had this suggestion:

> My only (not great) suggestion would be to perhaps grab the timestamp of the message quickly and paste it into your Slackbot channel for future reference or mark the channel as unread by long pressing on a message and selecting 'mark as unread'

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you star the post on your mobile, then view your starred posts on your desktop?

To be more specific: You can tap and hold on the message on mobile and choose **Star Message**, then on your desktop view your Starred Messages.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround (I upvoted). I wish there was that global feed, though.

Comment: Sadly it is only for those who never forget to star the message.  Too often I move on to realise later I need to go back. :/

Answer (score 0):

I found a project called [**Slack to RSS**](https://gozman.github.io/slack-rss/)

It is focused mainly on links inside a channel, but I am sure if you can grab the link there most be a way to get even more information as the tool needs to loop through everything to check for links.

At the moment I am looking for a tool or extension that provides me with an rss feed for a single Slack chat that I could embed on my website. If I will find something besser I will get back and let you know!